# Citrix Secure Gateway implentation issues

Tags: citrix

I hope someone is able to help as I have been trawling for information for some time and surely cannot be the only person having this issue.

We have a couple of XenApp farms and have decided to implement remote access using secure gateway. We have installed secure gateway on a separate server and configured it (after a bit of trial and error), we are now able to log into our Web server, we get the applications presented and the Citrix client (v4.1) launches, it sits on 'Connection in progress...' for a few seconds and then disappears. This leaves no event log entries on the client, the web server, the secure gateway or the destination Citrix Server.

I was originally getting an error until I realised that the STA was listening on 8080 instead of 80 but now everything seems to check out OK. I also needed to manually install the certificate but am fine with this as I understand why. We are using a SAN certificate if that makes a difference (the 'issued to: address' is not the same as the URL as it is one of the alternate names) - I have heard this can cause an issue but surely I would see an error reported somewhere.

All servers are on Windows 2008 R2 SP1, XenApp 6.5, Secure Gateway 3.3

I am trying to access a published app on a specific server (I have tried a few but for the sake of testing I am limiting myself to one server). The session never hits the XenApp server (I cannot see the user session under 'Connected users').

I am using HTTPS to connect to the citrix web server and have connected the site to use 'Gateway Direct' Secure Access with the address setting pointing to the FQDN of the secure gateway server.

I have run wireshark while trying to launch the application and have seen the connection the the web server, then to the secure gateway server. I see the 'server hello' packet, the 'certificate' packet, the 'new session ticket' and then a few comms on https (443). I cannot see anything after this relating to our citrix environment.

FYI I don't have the secure gateway in the DMZ yet and am accessing the web server from an internal workstation, just having the secure access configuration changed from 'Direct' to 'Gateway Direct' wiht the necessary configuration. Surely if the configuration was an issue I would get an event log entry somewhere?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a lot of info here and a lot to cover - this may be a bit broad for a Q & A, but I'll try and help. Firstly, does your new CSG server also have Web Interface installed?

Comment: Hi Dan, sorry I have just been following a lengthly 'how to' guide that was extremely helpful. I think the issue related to me having the wrong friendly name in my SAN certificate. I have issued a 30 day trial cert from geotrust and have got it working. FYI for anyone else having issues, follow this guide:

Comment: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/general/install-configure-citrix-web-interface-secure-gateway-part1.html

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it :)